# Warning Android API level 28 with ionic-v3 and cordova 6.3.0

Tags: android, api, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I used to publish an ionic app on google play but this morning I had the following warning: "Your application targets now level API 26. Nevertheless, it should now target level API 28 ..."

I'm using Cordova 6.3.0, how can I target API 28 with it?

Here is my ionic info :

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.12.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 6.3.0, ios 5.0.1
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, (and 14 other plugins)

System:

   NodeJS : v10.16.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.9.0
   OS     : macOS Mojave
   Xcode  : Xcode 10.2.1 Build version
```

I have no error message when building my app locally like I did until now, the warning is only on google play platform.

Here are the command line I generally use :

```
npm i
cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform add android@6.3.0 --save-exact

ionic cordova build android --prod --release

jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore somekeystorye.keystore /Users/user/Documents/dev/app/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release-unsigned.apk Name

~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/29.0.1/zipalign -v 4 /Users/user/Documents/dev/app/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release-unsigned.apk /Users/user/Documents/dev/app/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release-0.0.20.apk
```

Any idea?

**EDIT** 
Is seems that :

```
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />
```

Does the job as mentioned here : [Can cordova android@6.2.3 target SDK 26?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51912553/can-cordova-android6-2-3-target-sdk-26)
I have no warnings now.

Will try to check and come back later to keep you in touch

Comment: add 28 SDK in android and then just install platform without adding version behind

Comment: I already added it, but it was still targeting API level 26. 
how do you install platform without adding version behind ?

Comment: ionic cordova platform add android

Comment: hey could you solve this warning?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

for me what works finaly was just this :

`<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />`

Answer (score 4):

After spend some time on this error i found this three solution.

### solution 1

```
ionic cordova platform rm android

ionic cordova platform add android@8.1
```

### solution 2

```
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />
```

### solution 3 (if above solution not work then only)

1. Follow this step

   1. Update Your sdk to api level 28 from android studio.
   2. Create new project with "ionic start".
   3. Copy paste your old code to this new created project and install your all plugin and it's Done!

Answer (score 1):

changing directly the `uses-sdk` is not the correct answer, at least not enough nor good answer...

you better update the cordova android *engine* to the latest version. Its default target sdk version is already **28**. (see https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/791 ). Only changing it in config.xml just returned with bunch of rarely errors.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/#engine

Answer (score 0):

This helped me:

On file:
paltforms/android/app/src/main/androidmanifest.xml

Change the 'android:targetSdkVersion' value:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
```

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/android-compatibility-api-level-cordova-or-ionic/8194/14

Answer (score 0):

Update Cordova, then build again.

```
npm i -g cordova
ionic cordova build --release android --prod
```